# Issue while unsubscribe Platform event

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, platform-event, unsubscribe

I have created Platform event called accountUpdate__e. Whenever the account is updated from Contact I need to refresh my account fields using platform events .I added my LWC component in Account record page. This is working fine.
But I have problem when I include unsubscribe event. It worked only the first time of account update from contact till I refresh the page. Is it really required to unsubscribe the event in my case.

LWC :

```
connectedCallback() {
    // Register error listener     
    this.channelName = '/event/accountUpdate__e';
    this.registerErrorListener();
    this.handleSubscribe();
}

handleSubscribe() {
    const messageCallback = (response) => {
        this.handleResponse(response);
    }

    subscribe(this.channelName, -1, messageCallback).then(response => {
        console.log('Subscription request sent to: ', JSON.stringify(response.channel));
        this.subscription = response;
    });
}

handleResponse(response) {
    getRecordNotifyChange([{
        recordId: this.recordId
    }]);
   
    
    //this.unsubscribeToMessageChannel();

}


unsubscribeToMessageChannel() {
    unsubscribe(this.subscription, response => {
        console.log('unsubscribe() response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    });
}
```

It is working fine . But when I uncomment "this.unsubscribeToMessageChannel();" it is working only the first time till I refresh the page.

```
Apex trigger:

    trigger RestrictContactByName on Contact (after insert, after update, after delete) {


 if(Trigger.IsAfter) {
  for(Contact con : Trigger.new) {
      accIds.add(con.AccountId);
  }


 }

  for(AggregateResult agr : [SELECT MAX(Total_Revenue__c) maxCost, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :accIds GROUP BY AccountId]) {
  Decimal max = (Decimal)agr.get('maxCost');
  Id accountId = (Id)agr.get('AccountId');
  accMap.put(accountId, max);


 }

  List<accountUpdate__e> eventlst = new List<accountUpdate__e>();



 for(Account acc : [SELECT Id, Max_Revenue__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accIds]) {
    acc.Max_Revenue__c = accMap.get(acc.Id);
    accsToUpdate.add(acc);
    accountUpdate__e ref = new accountUpdate__e();
    ref.Record_Id__c= acc.Id;
    eventlst.add(ref);


}



if(!accsToUpdate.IsEmpty()) {
  update accsToUpdate;
  if(!eventlst.IsEmpty()) {
        EventBus.publish(eventlst);
  }


 }

}
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean saying that it worked only for the first time? After next account updates, component fires again getRecordNotifyChange, although it shouldnt because of the fact that theoretically it's unsubscribed from the channel?

Comment: @user1974566 If i want to get the account updates continuously not once per page load unsubscribe the channel is not needed right ?

Comment: That's correct. If I understand your post correctly, your component work as expected from the code, so after first refresh it unsubscribes from the channel and it won't refresh again. Unsubscribing from the channel is done usually in disconnectedCallback() -> so when component is removed from the DOM, as reaction on the events after that point is not needed anymore.

Comment: @user1974566 yeah you are correct. It should be in disconnectedcallback() .Thanks a lot for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

```js
connectedCallback() {
    // Register error listener     
    this.channelName = '/event/accountUpdate__e';
    this.registerErrorListener();
    this.handleSubscribe();
}

handleSubscribe() {
    const messageCallback = (response) => {
        this.handleResponse(response);
    }

    subscribe(this.channelName, -1, messageCallback).then(response => {
        console.log('Subscription request sent to: ', JSON.stringify(response.channel));
        this.subscription = response;
    });
}

handleResponse(response) {
    getRecordNotifyChange([{
        recordId: this.recordId
    }]);
   
    
    //this.unsubscribeToMessageChannel();

}


unsubscribeToMessageChannel() {
    unsubscribe(this.subscription, response => {
        console.log('unsubscribe() response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    });
}

disconnectedCallback() {
       
        console.log('child disconnected callback');
        this.unsubscribeToMessageChannel();
    }
```